# Cannot set property 'data' of undefined while access rest API in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am having error as

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined

I try fetch the data from rest api in angularjs using Http get method, Here the code

```
 getData(){
    this.http({method: 'GET',url:URL})
   .then(function(response) {
       console.log(response.data.id);
       this.data=response.data;// these line shows the error(TypeError: Cannot set property 'setdata' of undefined)
  });
```

}

Here `console.log(response.data.id);` print the id as `123456789` and  `console.log(response.data);` print the entire JSON data.

> But While assign the `response.data`to `this.data` shows error. But  assign the `response.data`to `var data` doesn't show error.

Please help me to store the response.data in this.data

Comment: please post more relevant code, also initialization of `this.data`

Comment: Why you are using this you can use $scope.data.

Comment: `(function(response) { ... }).bind(this)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the line `this.data = response.data` `this` is referencing the `then` callback and not your angular's scope. So the error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined` is for the `data` property you are trying to access within `this`.

Try to save your scope somehow and then use it within the callback.

An example is the famous `var vm = this;` and then in the callback do `vm.data = response.data`